# Convert a time calculation to time in HH:MM

Tags: sql-server, formatting, difference

I am looking to create a calculation in SQL Server that will display the time difference in `HH_MM` from a `time` column.

For example, the difference in hours and minutes between

```
5:45 PM - 3:30 PM = 2:15 (desired output)
```

The closest I have been able to get is this:

```
CONVERT(TIME,cals_END_time - cals_START_time) = 02:15:00.0000000
```

How do I go about 'trimming' it down to 2:15?

Comment: Um, `convert(varchar(5),xxx)`?

Comment: Tried that and got this message - level 16, state 1, 'The data types char and char are incompatible in the subtract operator.'

Comment: In addition to your existing cast- and you shouldn't subtract times anyway.

Comment: Please specify the datatype of all relevant columns

Comment: 1900-01-01 15:30:00.000

Comment: It can't be a time column as that gives an error, must be datetime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the columns are `datetime`, use the `format` function to *format* the time value:

```
select format(cast(cals_end_time - cals_start_time as time), N'h\:mm')
from (values
    (cast('2022-07-07 15:30:00' as datetime), cast('2022-07-07 17:45:00' as datetime))
) as tests(cals_start_time, cals_end_time)
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=51136dc1d3c8cf7af083edab90143c97)

Comment: I get "Operand data type time is invalid for subtract operator." with that

Comment: Convert the two values to datetime to do the subtraction.  The columns might be datetime, not time.

Comment: I am guessing it is actually datetime (based on OPs "working" attempt)

Comment: Note that format is a fairly slow performance wise. So there might be a faster way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add/subtract dates/datetimes you need to use the relevant functions to do so as follows:

```
select *, convert(varchar(5), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, [TimeOut], TimeIn), convert(time, '00:00'))) TimeDifference
    -- , CONVERT(TIME, [TimeOut], TimeIn) -- gives an error anyway?
from (
    values
    (convert(time, '05:45 PM'), convert(time, '03:30 PM'))
) x (TimeIn, [TimeOut]);
```

Returns:

| TimeIn | TimeOut | TimeDifference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17:45:00.0000000 | 15:30:00.0000000 | 02:15 |